# How to deploy to artifactory from azure pipeline?

Tags: azure, curl, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I'm trying to copy files to artifactory from my Azure pipeline but getting error:

> "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it."

This used to work fine but I suspect someone has blocked me somehow.

If I try to deploy the file manually within Artifactory, the error shows:

> "Error deploying these files: my-linux-shell-script.sh -
> artifactory-build-info:path/to/repo/my-linux-shell-script.sh could not
> be deployed.  Build Info repositories only supports build-info.json
> files."

Assuming I could get the Artifactory server's public key, I wouldn't know where to install it on Azure.

I can view all our files within Jfrog Artifactory but can no longer deploy to them.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get issuer certificate" usually means that your server (client) does not have the target's server trusted certificates.
You can ignore it by adding the -k flag or -insecure to the cURL command.

With regards to the artifactory-build-info repository, it will only support to deploy json files that have valid build name, build number and timestamp. There is another possibility that the deploy repository might have not been selected correctly rather the repository "artifactory-build-info" is selected, if that is the case, "artifactory-build-info" will not allow artifacts to be deployed as it only allows a valid JSON files. Please validate.

Comment: Thank you Gaja!  Adding the -k option worked.  When I try to deploy manually it only gives me the artifactory-build-info repo as an option, not the repo I want to use.  That's another matter I'll ask our IT about.